# RPy2 application iis deployment issue

Tags: python, r, iis, rpy2

I have developed an Flask Python REST application. When I run the application in VisualStudio all the functionalities are working correctly. But when I deploy to iis server all the methods are working except a method where RPy2 involved.

That particular method contains the following code.

```
r("library(e1071)")
r("library(kernlab)")
r.assign("traindata",traindf)
r.assign("testdata",testdf)
r("model <- ksvm(X{0} ~ ., data = traindata, kernel = 'rbfdot', degree = 3, coef0 = 0, cost = 1, nu = 0.5, na.action = na.omit, scale = TRUE)".format(testtopicid))
results = r("result <- predict(model, testdata)")
```

The exception I am getting from Python code is

> Error in library(e1071) : there is no package called 'e1071'

It seems this error message is from R.

I suspect that the problem with iss PATH settings.

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you run `install.packages("e1071")` on the IIS server's installation of *R*?

Comment: I installed R packages to the machine and it is working when I run with visual studio. But I didn't install like r("install.packages('e1071')"). I am not clear what you mean by "IIS server's installation of R".

Comment: It isn't obvious to me that the two are on the same computer, but if they are, what does `r(".libPaths()")` return in both environments?

Comment: Thanks r2evans for your help. I found the issue and rectified. r(".libPaths()") was giving me two different paths in the local environment (given both R_User and R_Home) and server environment (given only R_Home). So I installed the R packages in the library folder of R_Home, then it is working. Thanks again.